# It is right if someone committed Zina but wants to suicide instead of stoning himself to death

Tags: hadith-interpretation

I want to ask you about punishment of Zina.

What I knew is that the punishment of Zina is stoning the committed person until he Die.

But what if I want to suicide instead of stoning?

I know that if I go for stoning, people will spread this news like a wildfire. Because of that my parents and my family will face so many problems because of me.

It is my fault not my family's then why they face all these problems?

Can I suicide? I knew it’s a weird question. I don't even want to suicide but I want to know about this matter.

Answer (score 8):

**1**.There are several conditions that must be satisfied without which one can not receive the punishment of stoning:

1. Four just male must have witnessed the sin(excuse my language, I mean the exact act of penetrating) with their own eyes. So quoting the testimonies of four just male is not acceptable.
2. Their testimonies have to be exactly the same. If one of the testimonies differed from the others they would all get punished for defaming people of adultery.
3. All the witnesses must testify at the same court of law.
4. If the fornicator did not have a legal wife or husband, he/she would not be stoned to death.Instead, they would just be given a hundred lashes.
5. If the fornicator decided to confess to his/her sin, four confessions must be made at four different courts of law. So confessing for four times at the same court will not prove anything.

**2**. As you can see, proving adultery is almost impossible unless the corruption widely spread throughout the society. Can you even begin to imagine How possibly four Just people could find out about the ins and outs of this sin?

**3**.There are two kinds of sin:

1. Private sins which have nothing to do with the society. They have no negative impact on the people. For instance, drinking wine or watching porn scenes in private.
2. Public sins that can be seen by the people which means that they are likely to influence others by becoming commonplace or even turning into a norm!

All sins for which certain worldly punishments have been imposed, fall into the second category because the spiritual health of society has always been of crucial importance in Islam.Therefore, there would be no worldly punishment for sins as long as they did not result in others finding out about them. However, when it comes to punishments in the Day Of Judgement , there is no exception to the sins whether personal or public ones UNLESS one has repented of them.

> **وَ الَّذينَ إِذا فَعَلُوا فاحِشَةً أَوْ ظَلَمُوا أَنْفُسَهُمْ ذَكَرُوا اللَّهَ فَاسْتَغْفَرُوا لِذُنُوبِهِمْ وَ مَنْ يَغْفِرُ
> الذُّنُوبَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ وَ لَمْ يُصِرُّوا عَلى‏ ما فَعَلُوا وَ هُمْ
> يَعْلَمُونَ**
>
> and those who, when they commit an indecent act or
> wrong themselves, remember Allah, and plead] Allah's [forgiveness for
> their sins and who forgives sins except Allah? and who do not persist
> in what they have committed while they know.(3:135)
>
> **أُولئِكَ جَزاؤُهُمْ مَغْفِرَةٌ مِنْ رَبِّهِمْ وَ جَنَّاتٌ تَجْري مِنْ تَحْتِهَا الْأَنْهارُ خالِدينَ فيها وَ نِعْمَ أَجْرُ
> الْعامِلينَ**    Their reward is forgiveness from their Lord, and
> gardens with streams running in them, to remain in them] forever [.
> How excellent is the reward of the workers!(3:136)

This point should also be noted that we as Muslims are not entitled of possessing even our own lives. No sin can compare with Allah's mercy and compassion, no matter how big it might be.

Comment: Barak Allah-u- Feek brother Amin.. Such a great answer ma sha' Allah

Answer (score 3):

**Do not even think about suicide.**

Suicide is much bigger sin that Zina. It is ending your own life with out God's will. Do not punish yourself for something that can be forgiven by Allah.

Is is very much possible that God is aware of your guilt and has already forgiven you. If it was just Zina and not Zina by Jabbar, you have not violated anyone. It is only between you and God and God might well forgive it too. Try to be a better person next time. Mary the girl if you think that would lessen your burden. But do not put yourself under self punishment, esp taking your own life.

Answer (score 2):

The act of zinah, in order for it to proved and hence be punishable, needs to have a certain number (4; but not sure, and the number is different in case of male and female) of witnesses (eye AFAIK), and there are certain criteria (no previous record of false statements etc) that needs to fulfilled for a witness to be registered/considered.

There was a case in which women came to Ali (as) and confessed that she had commited zinah. Ali told her go you haven't done so and seek forgiveness. She repeated the confession and asked to be punished several times but on all instances he said go you haven't done so and seek forgiveness. (I might be missing or adding some wrong details here but the moral is the same).

That said, you can't punished until the act is proven by the Islamic law (briefly stated above). And you don't have the right to commit suicide under any condition. Whether you could or should be punished.

Comment: nicely said... this also reminds me of another hadith... in which a women came to Hazrat Ali and said she had committed Zinah in order to get food to feed her dying children, because she was poor and could not adequately feed her children. So Hazrat Ali said, go you are free from the sin of Zinah because as it says in the Qur'an: If a person commits sin out of hunger then the shame is not on the sin, but on the society that let that person to starve, so much so that he had to go to extreme measures to live.

Comment: nice answer and comment but Please put complete references ....

Answer (score 1):

Big rule: being disappointed to  Allah forgiveness means you are not muslim to God.

Solution is easy Tobah and never do the Zinah again. If you made a baby you should take care of it.

just beleive in Allah who is the greatest forgiver.
suicides means you: did zinah, you are not muslim; killed himself
Tobah means: you know you did wrong, you wont do it again, your are muslim, and believe in Allah forgiveness

Answer (score 1):

First of all Zina's maximum punishment **is not** stoning. Its maximum punishment is 100 lashes and that too only when you are utterly reckless and stupid enough to have committed it in public (with at least 4 witnesses). Stoning is merely a fantasy of deranged. Stoning for simply Zina, is not grounded in Islam.

What you do in your private life, is a matter between you and God alone and Islam doesn't concern itself with it. It only enforces a punishment if your actions lead to the destruction of structure in the society. If you committed Zina in privacy, the matter is between you and God alone. IMO you should repent, seek purity for yourself and pledge yourself not to repeat it again. You are probably not even entitled to a minor punishment, why would you want to commit suicide? Your guilty conscience is clouding your ability to think sensibly. Hopefully, with repentance you would find yourself at peace.